# Serializing / De-serialization inherited class with JMS Seralizer

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle

To keep things simple i have

```
/*
 * @JMS\Discriminator(field = "type", map = {
 *     "one": "...\ItemOne",
 *     "two": "...\ItemTwo"
 * })
 */
Abstract Class Item {}
.
.
.
class ItemOne extends Item {/* Contains multiple properties */}
class ItemTwo extends Item {/* Contains multiple properties */}

class Example
{
      /**
        * @var Item[] $items
        * 
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="...\Items", mappedBy="holder",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
        */
      protected $items;
}
```

Once i Serialize this entity using FOSRestBundle everything looks good, i get the array of items and each element will have a discriminator field but upon de-serializing i get the following error

```
"You must define a type for ...\Example::$items."
```

So to solve this issue i added

```
/**
  * @ORM\...
  * @JMS\Type("ArrayCollection<...\Item>")
  */
protected $items;
```

This time the serialized `$items` seems to be limited to the parent class `Item` all the objects will lose any properties related to the children `ItemOne` & `ItemTwo` and will be serialized without any discriminator field so de-seralization will fail with the error

```
"The discriminator field name "type" for base-class "...\Item" was not found in input data."
```

How can i solve this issue ?

**EDIT** 
as @erlangb suggested this seems to be a common issue in `JMS Serializer`  https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/292

**though i couldn't get this to work using the mentioned workaround**

```
/**
 * @JMS\Discriminator(field = "type", map = {"car": "...\Test\Car", "moped":"...\Test\Moped"})
 */
abstract class Vehicle {

    public $id;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {

    /**
     *@JMS\Type("integer")
    */
    public $id;
    /**
     *@JMS\Type("string")
     */
    public $car_at;

    /**
     * @JMS\VirtualProperty
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return 'car';
    }
}

class Moped extends Vehicle {

    /**
     *@JMS\Type("integer")
     */
    public $id;
    /**
     *@JMS\Type("string")
     */
    public $moped_at;

    /**
     * @JMS\VirtualProperty
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return 'moped';
    }

}

class Saloon
{
    /**
     *@JMS\Type("integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @JMS\Type("...\Test\Vehicle")
     */
    public $veichle;
}

    //In controller
    $car = new Car();
    $car->id = 1; 
    $car->car_at = "car";

    $car2 = new Moped();
    $car2->id = 2; 
    $car2->moped_at = "moped";


    $saloon = new Saloon();
    $saloon->veichle = $car2;
    $json = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($saloon,'json');
    $saloon_des = $this->get('jms_serializer')->deserialize($json,'...\Saloon','json');
```

still getting

```
 The discriminator field name "type" for base-class "...\Test\Vehicle" was not found in input data.
```

or if i remove `@JMS\Type` from `Saloon->veichle` i get

```
The discriminator field name "type" of the base-class "...\Test\Vehicle" conflicts with a regular property of the sub-class "...\Test\Moped".
```

Comment: have you found the solution? Having the same issue right now.

Comment: as discussed below it seems it's a bug, user `scasei` on github created a patch but i didn't have the time to test it yet. you can read more about the issue here: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/292

Answer (score 3):

there is a Known problem. I've encountered the same problem some years ago. I don't know if they fixed that, but have a look here: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/292

Now I'm looked that there is in the jms serialzier this annotation:

```
/**
* @Discriminator(field = "type", map = {"car": "Car", "moped": "Moped"})
*/
abstract class Vehicle { }
class Car extends Vehicle { }
class Moped extends Vehicle { }
```

You can set a virtual property like:

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
    /**
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return 'car';
    }
}

class Moped extends Vehicle {
    /**
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return 'moped';
    }
}
```

Try in this way

Comment: thank you for your answer, i tried that way i got the following error `The discriminator field name \"type\" of the base-class \"...\Item" conflicts with a regular property of the sub-class \"...\ItemOne"`

Comment: Probably you have an item named type in the ItemOne. Try to remove it, or change de discriminator field "type" with "discr" and the method getType in getDiscr

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried using the same example mentioned and still getting the same issue, am i doing anything wrong there ? please check my edit, Many Thanks!

Comment: same `The discriminator field name "type" of the base-class "Entity\Test\AbstractUser" conflicts with a regular property of the sub-class "Entity\Test\User"`

Comment: Ok try to remove the property type from the abstract class' The object will serialized. It works well in deserialization as well:

Comment: This is a gist, let me know if it works :D https://gist.github.com/danieledangeli/7fd178e20c4e91246308

Comment: Thank you for your time, I updated your gist to https://gist.github.com/laithar/9e4c3641d0dbfa3c1f02 the `Address` seraliztion/deseraliztion won't work

Comment: Yes I know, an this issue is exactly the one that I commented on git hub. I'll try to find a solution or workaround for that because I'm interested as well

Comment: yeah, i will try to find a solution for this, i guess the problem is in the `Type` annotation since it works if you directly serialize the object, anyways will keep you posted in case i came on a solution for this, Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @JMS\Discriminator(field = "type", map = {
 *    "user": "User",
 *    "mod": "Moderator"
 * })
 */
abstract class AbstractUser
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("integer")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    public $name
}

class Moderator extends AbstractUser
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    public $foo;
}

class User extends AbstractUser
{
    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    public $bar;
}
```

This is my test:

```
public function testSerializer()
{
    $data = new Moderator();
    $data->foo = 'foo';
    $data->name = 'daniele';
    $serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
    $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');

    $obj = $serializer->deserialize($jsonContent, '..MyBundle\...\AbstractUser',     json');
    $this->assertTrue(get_class($obj), 'MyBundle....\Moderator');

}
```

I've simplified the namespace, but it works

Comment: I really appreciate your generous help! your example works perfectly but can you try to create a new class for example `Address` with a public property `user` and add the `$data` from your example to an instance of the `Address` once you serialize the Address the `type` wont be in the seralized json anymore. in my example, if i serialize `Car` it works but once i do Saloon it doesn't.